# How to utilize the full window width with eLayoutType.application of basic theme?

Tags: abp

UI: Angular

I'm using the `eLayoutType.application`, but on the bigger screen there is always too much spacing on both sides of the page.
[please see this pic for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WL15.png)

I guess it has something to do with the `checkWindowWidth()` of the `LayoutService` ?

How can I change it to utilize the full window width on the larger screen? (my app is supposed to be used on the larger screen/window only, so this spacing is nothing but wasting space for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following code in the `styles.scss` file under the `src` folder, it worked for me, I hope it will work for you

```
@media screen and (min-width: 2500px){
  .container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl {
    max-width: 2000px;
  }
}
```

[image]

You can play with pixels according to your own needs.